# How to put non-editable elements in JPGraph

Tags: java, swing, graph, jframe, jgraphx

Im working on a code that shows a full graph and uses Dijkstra’s algoritm 
to show the shortest path. But the problem is: it doesnt simply visaluizate things, they're all editable and interactible.

I just need to visualize "the graph" and no to: move, edit, add, or make any interaqction with nodes and/or edges.

In this simple Jframe is where I've been trying to eliminate those interactions. But i have been failing:

```
public class Actions extends JFrame {

private mxGraph graph;
private mxGraphComponent graphComponent;

public Actions() {
    super("JGraph - labyrinth");
    initGUI();
}

private void initGUI() {
    setSize(800,600);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    graph = new mxGraph();
    graphComponent = new mxGraphComponent(graph);
    graphComponent.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 400));
    getContentPane().add(graphComponent);

    Object parent = graph.getDefaultParent();

    graph.getModel().beginUpdate();

    graph.insertVertex(parent, null, "TEST", 30, 80, 100, 50);

    graph.getModel().endUpdate();
}
```

}

So this program generates a node with the "TEST" String as name. The problem is: i can interact with this single node, i can move it everywhere, i can make many new edges as i want from the "TEST" node. And i dont want that, i just want to visaluizate my graph, no to interact with it.

**EDIT**: I managed to make the node unmovable, but I can still create / interact with its edges. This is the code i added:

```
   graph.setCellsLocked(true);
    graph.setVertexLabelsMovable(false);
    graph.setEdgeLabelsMovable(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try extending mxGraph and overriding the isCellSelectable method.

```
public class Graph extends mxGraph {

    @Override
    public boolean isCellSelectable(Object cell) {
           return false; 
    }

}
```